# Accessing Google datastore in javascript in jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-app-engine, charts, google-cloud-datastore

I have a data in the datastore and I would like to graph them using Google chart in my jsp file. I can make a datatable with what I want to graph in the java part of the file but I do not know how to transfer this datatable to the javascript part since you need the datatable in javascript to use Google chart to graph it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery or Ajax to request json (in array maybe) from your code in server (Servlet or Spring Controller). [Here](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-and-jquery-integration.html) is the example of Spring MVC and JQuery Integration.